# Javascript innerHtml repeat

Tags: javascript

I'm writing the innerHtml but the div was repeating again and again. I don't know how to solve. Thanks for help.

My code below:

```
for(b=0; b<Object.keys(getCurrentAM).length; b++){

    var num = Object.keys(getCurrentAM)[b];
    var dutyData = getCurrentAM[num];

    var res = num.replace("A", "P");
    var newD2 = num.replace("A", "");

    var amDuty = document.getElementById('' + num + '_amDuty');
    var locationDuty = document.getElementById('' + num + '_locationDuty');
    var pmDuty = document.getElementById('' + res + '_pmDuty');

    amDuty.style.display = 'block';
    locationDuty.style.display = 'block';
    pmDuty.style.display = 'block';

    if ((amDuty.getElementsByTagName('na').length == 0) && (locationDuty.getElementsByTagName('na').length == 0) && (pmDuty.getElementsByTagName('na').length == 0) ){          

        amDuty.innerHTML = '<div class="dutyChangeSize">'+ amDuty.innerHTML + '<br/>' + locationDuty.innerHTML + '<br/>' + pmDuty.innerHTML + '</div>';
        locationDuty.innerHTML = '';
        pmDuty.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how big a number this is: `<Object.keys(getCurrentAM).length;`?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: You have a tag named `na`? Also, the `''` in `'' + num + '_amDuty'` etc. is unnecessary. Instead of manipulating the style directly, you are better off using classes. More basically, instead of structuring your program around IDs and laboriously constructing them and using them as variables for accessing DOM elements, it's better to simply deal with the DOM elements directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed class and used css to not display repeating of 
.

```
for(b=0; b<Object.keys(getCurrentAM).length; b++){

var num = Object.keys(getCurrentAM)[b];
var dutyData = getCurrentAM[num];

var res = num.replace("A", "P");
var newD2 = num.replace("A", "");

var amDuty = document.getElementById('' + num + '_amDuty');
var locationDuty = document.getElementById('' + num + '_locationDuty');
var pmDuty = document.getElementById('' + res + '_pmDuty');

amDuty.style.display = 'block';
locationDuty.style.display = 'block';
pmDuty.style.display = 'block';

if ((amDuty.getElementsByTagName('na').length == 0) && (locationDuty.getElementsByTagName('na').length == 0) && (pmDuty.getElementsByTagName('na').length == 0) ){          

   amDuty.className = "dutyChangeSize";

   amDuty.innerHTML = ''+ amDuty.innerHTML + '<br/>' + locationDuty.innerHTML + '<br/>' + pmDuty.innerHTML + '';
   locationDuty.innerHTML = '';
   pmDuty.innerHTML = '';
}
    }
```

--> CSS

br + br {display:none}